# To have L^{p} in Bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

One article has words `$L^{p}$` boundedness in the title.

**How can you have such an operator in Bibtex?**

Comment: Just edit your `bib` file and write as in plain TeX.

Comment: Type `{$L^{p}$}-boundedness`; the additional braces will keep BibTeX from lowercasing the contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid BibTeX applies any capitalization rule to an element of a title, wrap it in braces:

```
title={{$L^{p}$}-boundedness is cool},
```

This applies also to persons' names or Roman numbers in titles

```
title={A Proof of {Fermat's Last Theorem}, {II}},

title={A remark on {Grothendieck} categories},
```

In the first example, we leave to the bibliographic style the decision whether “Proof” will be capitalized or not, but since “Fermat's Last Theorem” is a name, we don't want it to be modified.